# Better code to stop flickering and stay in the same sheet with ComboBox feature

Tags: vba, excel

I am using a ComboBox in sheet1 and when I select the drop down project name from the ComboBox it is flickering several times (though I have mentioned "Application.ScreenUpdating = False" line of code) and moving to the different sheet.  I have mentioned my existing code below.

Just wanted to know is there a better code which should not flicker and stay in the same sheet.

```
Private Sub ShowRanges1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call unprotect_sheet

Dim i As Integer
i = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex

Select Case i
    Case 0

    Call Clear_ComboBox

    With Sheets("Overview").ComboBox
        .Activate
    Call unprotect_sheet
        .AddItem "All"
        .AddItem "Phase1"
        .AddItem "Phase2"
        .AddItem "Phase3"
        .AddItem "Phase4"
        .AddItem "Phase5"
   End With

        Sheets("Cover_Page").Range("F9").Value = "BPO"
        Sheets("Overview").Activate
        Sheets("Overview").Range("All").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Budget").Activate
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B5:D8").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Budget").Range("A1").Select
        Sheets("Overview").Activate
        Sheets("Overview").Range("A1").Select

    Case 1

    Call Clear_ComboBox

    With Sheets("Overview").ComboBox
        .Activate
    Call unprotect_sheet
        .AddItem "All."
        .AddItem "Phase1"
        .AddItem "Phase2"
        .AddItem "Phase3"
        .AddItem "Phase4"
    End With

        Sheets("Cover_Page").Range("F9").Value = "IT"
        Sheets("Overview").Activate
        Sheets("Overview").Range("IT_Phase").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Overview").Range("Phase1").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Budget").Activate
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B5:D7").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B8:D8").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Budget").Range("A1").Select
        Sheets("Overview").Activate
        Sheets("Overview").Range("A1").Select

    Case 2

    Call Clear_ComboBox

    With Sheets("Overview").ComboBox
        .Activate
    Call unprotect_sheet
        .AddItem "Phase1"
    End With

        Sheets("Cover_Page").Range("F9").Value = "Purchase"
        Sheets("Overview").Activate
        Sheets("Overview").Range("Purchase_Phase").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Overview").Range("Phase2,Phase3,Phase4,Phase5").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Budget").Activate
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B5:D8").Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Budget").Range("A1").Select
        Sheets("Overview").Activate
        Sheets("Overview").Range("A1").Select
    End Select

Call protect_sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen flickering and moving to different sheets might be caused by the excessive use of `Activate` and `Select`, two actions that are highly unnecessary in most cases, including this. Try the following modified code.

```
Private Sub ShowRanges1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Call unprotect_sheet

Dim i As Integer
i = Me.ComboBox1.ListIndex

Select Case i

    Case 0

        Call Clear_ComboBox

        With Sheets("Overview").ComboBox
            Call unprotect_sheet
            .AddItem "All"
            .AddItem "Phase1"
            .AddItem "Phase2"
            .AddItem "Phase3"
            .AddItem "Phase4"
            .AddItem "Phase5"
       End With

        Sheets("Cover_Page").Range("F9").Value = "BPO"
        Sheets("Overview").Range("All").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B5:D8").EntireRow.Hidden = False

    Case 1

        Call Clear_ComboBox

        With Sheets("Overview").ComboBox
            Call unprotect_sheet
            .AddItem "All."
            .AddItem "Phase1"
            .AddItem "Phase2"
            .AddItem "Phase3"
            .AddItem "Phase4"
        End With

        Sheets("Cover_Page").Range("F9").Value = "IT"
        Sheets("Overview").Range("IT_Phase").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Overview").Range("Phase1").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B5:D7").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B8:D8").EntireRow.Hidden = True

    Case 2

        Call Clear_ComboBox

        With Sheets("Overview").ComboBox
            Call unprotect_sheet
            .AddItem "Phase1"
        End With

        Sheets("Cover_Page").Range("F9").Value = "Purchase"
        Sheets("Overview").Range("Purchase_Phase").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        Sheets("Overview").Range("Phase2,Phase3,Phase4,Phase5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
        Sheets("Budget").Range("B5:D8").EntireRow.Hidden = True


End Select

Call protect_sheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

It's basically the same code with all the `Activate` and `Select` removed and modified accordingly and properly.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: great improvement in this code.  Now every time it is activating "Overview" sheet.  Is there a way to stay in "Sheet1" even after selecting the project name from the ComboBox? I don't want to go to Overview sheet.

Comment: Just remove the `.Activate` under the `Overview` part in the beginning. Edited my code above. However, please note that if your `unprotect_sheet` macro is taking the `ActiveSheet` as an argument, `Overview` will not be unprotected. Try the above code first if it works and let us know of results.

Comment: @Amrutha: Thanks for accepting. Let us know of any other issues.